# Pushing Java Gradle multiproject into Git

Tags: java, gradle, build, architecture, git-submodules

Description:
I have Java multiproject in Gradle, that has several subprojects and want to push them to Git.
I am going to map the subprojects to git submodules and use them in the parent repository .

The main goal is to maintain two crucial facilities:

1. easy and clear way of releasing components (subproject life cycle management)
2. have clear automated build that uses Gradle's "Composite Build"

Question:
Are there other ways to achieve it? Pros and cons?
I think the topic was discussed many times, would you please share your experience or sources describing it [best practices].